# Can one set global numberlike in thmtools?

Tags: theorems, package-options, thmtools

I want all of my theorem-like environments to be numbered as if they were all theorems. Using `thmtools` I can do this with code like this:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem[numberlike=theorem]{corollary}
\declaretheorem[numberlike=theorem]{lemma}
\declaretheorem[numberlike=theorem, style=definition]{definition}
```

Is there a global package option that sets the default `numberlike` behavior for newly declared theorems? For example, is there an option that would allow code like this:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[numberlike=theorem]{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\declaretheorem{corollary}
\declaretheorem{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style=definition]{definition}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this might be a bit excessive, you can employ [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) to fix the setting of keys in `\declaretheorem`:

```
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsthm,thmtools}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch
\xpatchcmd{\declaretheorem}{{thmdef}{#1}}{{thmdef}{numberlike=theorem,#1}}{}{}
\declaretheorem{corollary}
\declaretheorem{lemma}
\declaretheorem[style=definition]{definition}
\begin{document}
```

The above just adds `numberlike=theorem` to the list of keys supplied by the optional argument of `\declaretheorem[<options>]`.

Comment: I guess there is no better solution for now. Thanks.